# Applying border to SlidesJS frame is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml

I'm using SlidesJS jQuery plugin. Here it's : [slidesjs](http://www.slidesjs.com/)
I just want to apply border around slider. I edited css part like this :

```
#slides .slidesjs-container {
  margin-bottom:10px;
  border-color: #ff5566;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style:solid;
}
```

But there's no border on the right side. Other 3 sides have border. You can check out all of the codes from [here](http://pastebin.com/8QRiwjej)

You can download the examples from [here](https://github.com/nathansearles/Slides/archive/SlidesJS-3.zip) and try it on any example.
Please, help me. How can I apply border to all of the sides of slider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because its parent `overflow` is `hidden` `border` is not visible you can reduced the width to see the `border` try below code

```
#slides .slidesjs-container {
    margin-bottom:10px;
    border-color: #ff5566;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-style:solid;
    width: 1164px !important; /* <= Width is added here to show the border in basic-fade demo */
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much :) It's the exact solution.